# Tikz: Alligning paths in its entirety

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-chains

How can I align paths? I have two mindmaps:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,mindmap,chains}

\tikzset{grow cyclic list/.code={%
  \def\tikzgrowthpositions{{#1}}%
  \foreach \n [count=\i,remember=\i]in {#1}{}%
  \let\tikzgrowthpositionscount=\i%
  \tikzset{growth function=\tikzgrowcycliclist}}}
\def\tikzgrowcycliclist{%
  \pgftransformshift{%
    \pgfpointpolar{\tikzgrowthpositions[mod(\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1,\tikzgrowthpositionscount)]}%
      {\the\tikzleveldistance}}}

\tikzset{every node/.style={font={\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=blue!20, every child node/.style={concept}, start chain=going below, node distance=7cm]

\path node[concept, on chain] {Mathematical Modeling and Machine Learning} [clockwise from=90]
    child { node {clustering} [grow cyclic list={110,55}]
        child { node {K-means} }
        child { node {hie\-rar\-chi\-cal clustering} }
    }
;

\path node[concept, on chain] {Something else} [grow cyclic list={90,-90}]
    child { node {regression} [grow cyclic list={0}]
        child[level distance=10cm] { node {multivariable regression} }
    }
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

Here I have put the two root nodes `on chain`, and so they have a distance of 7cm (red in image).

#### First task:

I'd like the centers of the mindmaps to have a distance of 7cm (green).

#### Second task:

In a second scenario I'd like the distance of the mindmaps to have 3cm (orange).

#### Third task:

In a third scenario I'd like one of the above, but additionally I'd like to have the mindmaps centered:

[image]

How do I do these things? It does not have to be by chaining.

Comment: You can't do this with chains. You can only chain nodes - not paths. You can add the nodes in the mind maps to chains, but you can't add the paths. Or you could make a node to `fit` all the nodes in a map and add that to a chain. However, none of this will alter the placement or appearance of existing nodes, even if you add them to a chain. Adding a node to a chain only affects its location and, possibly, appearance, if the node is new.

Comment: I think it would be easiest to just draw the mind maps as separate pictures and place them appropriately that way.

Comment: @cfr: That is not an option, because the nodes of the mindmaps are connected with other nodes outside the maps. I tried to put the mindmaps into nodes with their own tikzpicture-environments but the result was total chaos.

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture` environments is not generally supported. Sometimes it works in simple cases, but the results are generally unpredictable and it is best avoided. But if you really need to work with the centre of the map, as opposed to the centre of a node within it, I don't think there is a straightforward solution. At least, I'm not aware of it. You can place something relative to the centre of the map once drawn, but anchoring a new map at its centre is more problematic.

Comment: As written right now, your question cannot be answered because you cannot do this with chaining. The library just doesn't support what you want. So I'd suggest editing your question to reflect what you really need rather than asking to do it in a specific way.

Comment: You can place them in separate pictures and still connect to other nodes if you use `remember picture`.

Comment: @cfr: I don't need chaining... what I want, I have shown in the image and the description of the tasks.

Comment: That's why you should edit the question ;).